# Get selected value of a dropdown list

Tags: drupal

I try to get the selected value of my select in Drupal (7), but the value of the select is always empty in my hook_submit() :| !

Below my code :

```
<?php
function gestionvideos_players_form() {
//I get my list of players from my database
$aPlayers = EasyVod_db::get_players();
    $options = array();
    if( empty($aPlayers) ) {
        $options[] = "no available player"; 
    }else{
        foreach( $aPlayers as $player ){
            $options[$player->iPlayer] = ucfirst($player->sName);
        }
    }

    $form['gestionvideos_player'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('Integration par defaut des videos'),
      '#description' => t('Selection du player par defaut : '),
    );
    $form['gestionvideos_player']['selectplayer'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#options' => $options,
    );
    $form['gestionvideos_player']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Choisir ce player'),
    );
    return $form;
}

function gestionvideos_players_form_submit($form, &$form_state){

  drupal_set_message("test ".$form_state['values']['selectplayer']);
  //I set my player in my session variable
  $oPlayer = EasyVod_db::get_player( intval($form_state['values']['selectplayer']) );
  $_SESSION['player'] = $oPlayer ->player;
}
?>
```

I would really appreciate some help because I really don't understand what it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting

$form['#tree'] = true;

inside your form builder function then try dumping:

$form_state['values']['gestionvideos_player']['selectplayer']